# If $A^2 = A$ then $A$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, idempotents

I've stumbled upon this question in my assignment:

> Prove if $A_{nxn}(\mathbb C)$ with $A^2 = A$, then $A$ is diagonalizable

My first thought is to solve for $p(A)$ where $p(x)  = x^2 - x$ and you get real roots.
Would that be sufficient in showing that $A$ is diagonalizable given you get real roots?

Comment: More generally if a square matrix $A$ satisfies $p(A)=0$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial without multiple roots, then $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: I think it should be added that what you wrote is true over algebraically closed fields, not over any field.

Comment: Yes, that is what I forgot to add.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mark I can't see what we need algebraically closed field here for: the claim is true over any field...

Comment: @DonAntonio  This matrix is not diagonalizable over the reals: $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.  Its characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2+1$, which has no multiple roots.

Comment: Yeah, exactly the example I was going to give. This matrix satisfies $p(A)=0$ for $p(x)=x^2+1$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool That matrix doesn't fulfil $\;A^2=A\;$ so it doesn't apply to it the basic condition of the question...

Comment: @DonAntonio In my comment, I wasn't talking just about $p(x)=x^2-x$.  I meant ***any*** polynomial without multiple roots.  That is why being in a field in which the polynomial splits is important.  Of course, $p(x)=x^2-x$ splits in any field.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I don't really mind that: in my first comment I was addressing Mark who commented "I think it should be added that what you wrote is true over algebraically closed fields, not over any field" . There's no name there and I didn't even read your comment before. It looks like he's addressing the OP...!

Comment: Mark was addressing me.  The comment would have made no sense if he was addressing the OP.

Comment: @DonAntonio I was replying to the comment, not addressing OP. Of course the original question would be the same over any field, since $x^2-x$ trivially splits in any field.

Comment: @Mark If you don't pin someone and never even mention his(her) name it is usually assumed you mean to address the OP. Simple logic. And what is trivial and "of course" to you may well not be so for others.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool The comment would be wrong if he was addressing the OP, as I remarked...The problem is not pinning somone and not even writing down his(her) name.

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, if we are discussing properties of algebrically closed fields then I believe we both know that $x^2-x$ splits in any field. And ok, I'll pin next time when it's not clear who I'm replying to. Not sure why we have such a long discussion about that.

Comment: @Mark It indded was long because you didn't acknowledged you made a mistake: not naming the person you're addresing. Now that we're reached an agreement we can end this boring discussion. Take care and keep safe.

Answer (score 6):

Note that if $A=0$ or $A=I$ then $A$ is trivially diagonalizable. Otherwise, $x(x-1)$ must be the minimal polynomial of this matrix. And there is a known theorem which states that a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial splits into a product of distinct linear factors.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it without the "known theorem", let $N$ be the null space (=kernel) of $A$ and $R$ the range (=column space) of $A$.  Note that if $y = A x \in R$, 
$A y = A^2 x = Ax = y $, so $N \cap R = \{0\}$.  Moreover, for any $v \in \mathbb C^n$,
$v - A v \in N$ since $A(v - Av) = Av - A^2 v = 0$.  Thus $v = (v - Av) + Av \in N + R$,
i.e. $v$ is the sum of a member of $N$ and a member of $R$.

To diagonalize $A$, take  the union of a basis of $N$ and a basis of $R$.
Using the fact that $\mathbb C^n = N + R$ with $N \cap R = \{0\}$, this is easily seen to form a basis of $\mathbb C^n$.  Since $A x = 0$ for $x \in N$ and $A x = x$ for $x \in R$, $A$ is diagonal in this basis, with diagonal entries $0$ corresponding to the basis of $N$ and $1$ corresponding to the basis of $R$.

Answer (score 0):

$A^2=A$ means that $\operatorname{col}A$ is a subset of the eigenspace of $1$. Moreover, $\ker A$ is the eigenspace of $0$. Therefore, $\operatorname{col} A\cap \ker A=\{0\}$, which means that $\operatorname{col}A+\ker A=\operatorname{col}A\oplus \ker A$. By rank-nullity, $\operatorname{col}A\oplus \ker A=\Bbb R^n=V_1\oplus V_0$ ($n$ being the size of the matrix).